# Qt creator SSL enable

Tags: qt, ssl, qt-creator

I have a program built with Qt creator. I need to send an https post to Google's C2DM servers.

When I try using QSslSocket, it says that my SSL is not working.

The Qt documentation states that it doesn't ship with SSL support for legal reasons, and QSslSocket is just a wrapper and that I need to install OpenSSL myself. I've tried copying the DLLs but it still doesn't work. Can someone walk me through the steps of installing OpenSSL and getting it to work with Qt Creator?

Comment: Which dlls did you copy?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `QNetworkAccessManager`? I use something like this to post JSON to a web service:

```
void HttpPoster::post(){

  if(!manager)
     manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

  QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
  config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
  //config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1);

  QNetworkRequest request ;
  request.setUrl(QUrl("https://somehost.somedomain"));
  request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyApp");
  request.setRawHeader("Content-type", "text/json");

  request.setSslConfiguration(config);

  if(!reply){
     reply =  manager->post(request,m_Data);
  }

  connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),this,SLOT(handleErrors(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
  connect(reply,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),this,SLOT(handleSSLErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
  connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(replyFinished()));

}
```

There's some methods omitted (handle errors, handle replies, handle ssl errors, etc). You can find much better examples in the docs.